# Looping through same JavaScript function on multiple (html)elements property change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there a way to looping JavaScript function for multiple fields?

For e.g. I have 5 textboxes such as:

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
```

Now, Each of them does the same thing on "focusout" and hence I dont want to write five different JS functions for each of them:

```
$('#text1').focusout( {
.............
    });

$('#text2').focusout( {
.............
    });

$('#text3').focusout( {
.............
    });

$('#text4').focusout( {
.............
    });

$('#text5').focusout( {
.............
    });
```

How can I avoid writing five different functions here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on your comments to the provided answers, I'm guessing there's more to this question than what you're asking. Do you want to perform the EXACT same functionality to each textbox on focusout? Or do you need to know which box is losing focus so you can do something depending on which one it was?

Comment: @MrOBrian I have 5 text boxes where I'll enter student ID and there are five other text boxes which will display the student name based on what student ID I enter. SO, entering student Id in text1 will display student name in name1, entering student Id in text2 will display student name in name2 and so on. SO yes, in terms of execution, I want all of them (text1 through text5) to execute the same JQuery function, but depending on which Text box was updated(text1... text5) with student Id, I want respective Text box to be updated (name1...name5) with Student Names

Answer (score 1):

Use a common class:

```
<input type="text" class="focusClass" />
<input type="text" class="focusClass" />
```

and this JS:

```
$('.focusClass').focusout(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Other option is to join them together, but this way is harder to maintain:

```
$('#text1, #text2, #text3, #text4, #text5 ').focusout(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass the current id to jQuery function for a particular class name?

Answer (score 0):

In your selector, select all the elements you want to work with:

```
$('#text1, #text2, #text3, #text4, #text5')
```

Comment: each of these text box has another textbox attached to it. such as text1 = studentId1 and Name1 = StudentName1, text2 = StudentId2 Name2 = StudentName2... and so on. entering StudentId1 populates StudentName1 and so on... So if i do it your way, it will populate all Name textboxes(Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5) with the same name. I want them to be independent. Is there a way of identifying a particular text box in a group of textboxes having same class name?

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. I thought you wanted it to do the exact same thing for each text box? If you need it to have different functionality depending on the input box, stick to your original code. Also, you can get the id of an element using `.attr('id')`

Comment: I tried .attr('id') but it only returns the first id in the class, I have many textboxes in a class, is there a way to identifying textboxes any other way? like text1 could identify name1, text2 could identify name2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't makes sense to put the same class on all the elements, you may combine the selectors with a comma:

```
$('#text1, #text2, etc...., #text5').focusout( {
.............
});
```

Alternately, you could declare the function and then pass it as a parameter to each of your selectors through the focusout call:

```
var onFocusOut = function() {
 do something
};

$('#text1').focusout(onFocusOut);
$('#text2').focusout(onFocusOut);
$('#text3').focusout(onFocusOut);
$('#text4').focusout(onFocusOut);
$('#text5').focusout(onFocusOut);
```

Comment: each of these text box has another textbox attached to it. such as text1 = studentId1 and Name1 = StudentName1, text2 = StudentId2 Name2 = StudentName2... and so on. entering StudentId1 populates StudentName1 and so on... So if i do it your way, it will populate all Name textboxes(Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5) with the same name. I want them to be independent. Is there a way of identifying a particular text box in a group of textboxes having same class name?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a short way to do it...

```
$("#text" + [1,2,3,4,5].join(", #text")).focusout(function () {...});
```

But I'm wondering if you can't add a class to the elements so you can select them at once.

For example...

```
<input type='text' id="text1' class='textfield' />
<input type='text' id="text2' class='textfield' />
<input type='text' id="text3' class='textfield' />
```

Then use the following selector...

```
$(".textfield").focusout(function () {...});
```

Other option is that you have a parent container with an id which gives you the following option...

```
<div id="formfields">
    <input type='text' id="text1' class='textfield' />
    <input type='text' id="text2' class='textfield' />
    <input type='text' id="text3' class='textfield' />
</div>
```

The selector then looks like this...

```
$("#formfields input[type=text]").focusout(function () {...});
```

**Update** Added two more options to select your fields

Comment: each of these text box has another textbox attached to it. such as text1 = studentId1 and Name1 = StudentName1, text2 = StudentId2 Name2 = StudentName2... and so on. entering StudentId1 populates StudentName1 and so on... So if i do it your way, it will populate all Name textboxes(Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5) with the same name. I want them to be independent. Is there a way of identifying a particular text box in a group of textboxes having same class name?

Comment: @user793468 Added two more options for you! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the IDs of the text box to the jQuery functions to carry out your task..

try this:

```
function myFunction(IDofObject)
{
    $( "#"  + IDofObject  ).doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Can I pass IDs of text box to jQuery using elements class name?

Comment: How will i pass the ID to my function here?